# Examples of UX Web Application Diagrams

Tags: user-interface, diagram, user-experience, sequence-diagram

I am looking for some examples of ux diagrams, not so much from the technical perspective, but more from the user experience perspective.

Mainly keeping in mind all of the different states, logged in, not logged in, public profile, private profile, first time visiting page, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a tool for "wireframes"? - try http://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-creating-web-design-wireframes

Comment: Looking for more actual examples then tools also more of a flow or sequence diagram then wireframes

Answer (score 0):

There are UML diagrams such as the sequence diagram, activity diagram and state machine diagram, but these don't specifically model the user experience.

As part of the UX process, UX designers use storyboarding and user experience mapping to model a user's journey. Here is an article which goes into experience mapping: http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/the-anatomy-of-an-experience-map/